# How to add XML prolog with rust serde_xml

Tags: xml, rust, serde

can I add the XML prolog when serializing with `serde_xml?`

```rs
struct User {
  name:String,
  last_name:String
}
```

### becomes

```xml
<User>
  <name>Jimmy</name>
  <last_name>Foobar</last_name>
</User>
```

but I would like to have it with prolog:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<User>
  <name>Jimmy</name>
  <last_name>Foobar</last_name>
</User>
```

Comment: Assuming you mean [serde-xml-rs](https://crates.io/crates/serde-xml-rs) rather than the abandoned [serde_xml](https://crates.io/crates/serde_xml), I don't think it can do this for you.  But you could of course add the prolog yourself?